# Download multiple images using URL link from MS excel file

Tags: excel

I am New to Excel, I have multiple image URL's in excel file. I need to dynamically change the names and download the image in my local disk(D).

1.my file image :

[image]

In the SKU(column) we have single and multiple serial number with that number save the images in local disk and for example: 1. 59856_1.jpeg 2.59856_2.jpeg like this we have save the images, please advice me in excel formula.

Comment: copy the list and paste into any download manager (like IDM).

Comment: but, I need to  change dynamically the image names also.

Comment: use 'CONCATENATE()' function to create 'ren "C:\path\file1.jpg" "C:\path\file2.jpg"` string.. and paste in cmd. | (get the download done 1st)